# Link not active on storefront

Tags: magento2, link

I extended Magento_Catalog in a custom theme and added the following block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="lvluplink" after="product.info.price" template="Magento_Catalog::customline.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

the template:

```
<a class="primary action" href="https://google.com"><?= __('Custom Button') ?></a>
```

The link shows up in the store, but clicking the link does nothing. I am running Magento 2.3.4 in developer mode and have run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had developer hints on. This prevents any links or buttons from being clicked on the page. Turned off the hints and the link works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> 1.**app/design/frontend/Mage/Mohit/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/customline.phtml**

```
<a class="primary action" href="https://google.com"><?= __('Custom Button') ?></a>
```

> 2.**app/design/frontend/Mage/Mohit/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="lvluplink" after="product.info.price" template="Magento_Catalog::product/customline.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And after run the `php bin/magento c:f`

Output :-

[image]

And click button working fine.

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: So, move the template into the directory `product`?

Comment: It turns out that having developer hints on precludes clicking any buttons or links.

Comment: what you say i don't understand . so please explain me ...

Comment: I had the front end developer hints on. The hints stop the user from clicking on links/buttons.

Comment: you go to admin panel disable the developer debug hints ...